# How to go about web service security in Java

Tags: java, web-services, security, jboss

Does anyone have a recommendation about web service security architecture in Java (preferably under JBoss)?  Any recommended reading?

I want to expose a fairly rich web service to the world but the data are sensitive and it requires authentication from the current client (Flex), accessed via RPC.  I definitely do not want any server-side session state.

What's the best way to go about implementing security through web services in Java/JBoss and where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For web services security in JBoss, I would start by reading [8.4 WS-Security](http://jbossws.jboss.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=User_Guide#WS-Security) of the [JBossWS User Guide](http://jbossws.jboss.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=User_Guide).

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image: SOA Security]

Answer (score 0):

WSSE is simple and works well.

http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/12/17/dive.html

http://www.sixapart.com/developers/atom/protocol/atom_authentication.html